# 4 node Cluster Query

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

In a 4 node cluster 1.1.10, if we want to change underlying storage of one node, I am thinking of adopting following steps. Is this correct?

1. Take snapshop of the disks
2. Take the node down and take final snapshot and swap the storage
3. Bring the node up
4. Cassandra will automatically balance/catch up on the node

Step 2 is expected to take around 1 Hr. During this time cluster will take care of the customer queries.

Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Also for step 4, what happens if any users queries the data that resides on the node whose storage was swapped.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be better to add a new node, with appropriate storage, wait until Cassandra balance the cluster, then decommission the old node? Zero downtime, no need of snapshots taking. You can make a release from source - [Cassandra 1.1.10](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/releases/tag/cassandra-1.1.10).

Still, if you want to do it your way:

- make sure you know your enemy - Cassandra will use [hinted handoff](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_hh_c.html) mechanizm - check *max_hint_window_in_ms value*
- to be sure to avoid data resurrection, run `nodetool repair` on all nodes, check *GCGraceSeconds* value
- make sure your client's are using appropriate consistency level - ConsistencyLevel.ALL isn't good in this case

Comment: Tried that but issue was to get cassandra 1.1.10 version. I could not find the software anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @piotrwest, much appreciated for valuable information. Is there any way to check at backend level as to what queries are coming in from clients or in other words what consistency level is specified?

Comment: That depends on your client. If you don't specify the consistency level explicitly, check what is the default one.

Comment: I did my work. When i bring back my ec2 instance online after storage change, do i need to execute nodetool join command so that node joins cluster? What i found that in the output of nodetool info, it had false for gossip and thrift and i cant run cqlsh as it gives java errors. I restart node couple of times and then it fixes everything